# Filtering SQL profiler web services entries

Tags: sql-server, profiler

Is there a way to filter SQL profiler data to show only data from current user/session?

I tried using the LoginName or SessionLoginName filters, but the problem is that most of the calls are made by the application's web service and I see no indication who called this service.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not have the context of the end client when multiple tiers are involved so there is no trace column you can filter on to identify requests originating from a specific end client session.  The easiest method is to trace in an isolated test environment with a single client.

If the web service has an end client session context identifier, the service could specify the client session id as the `Application Name` in the connection string so that you can filter on a specific client session.  However, that should generally be done only in a test environment since a separate connection pool is created for each unique connection string.